# jquery-bootgrid cannot call reload function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

I can call the reload function in jquery-bootgrid by using `$.fn.bootgrid.Constructor.prototype.reload` but I encounter the error

```
TypeError: this.options is undefined
post = this.options.post;
```

Does anyone knows how I can call it properly?

I have seen a solution wherein he call the click event of the refresh button but I don't think that is a good solution if there are multiple jquery-bootgrid in the same page. All of them will make an ajax call at the same time which is not good.

Comment: Please take note that this is quite a new jquery plugin so it does not have many examples but i find his code great so I want to create resources where future users of it may refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also found the other solution with the fired event ("click") and was not quite happy with this workaround. So I tried

```
$('#grid-data').bootgrid('reload');
```

which is working like a charme.
Perhpaps you will give this a chance?

Michael